# defining a primary key in django maually

Tags: python, django-models

I am trying to define a primary key 'eid' for Employee database. I have tried following code

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    eid = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    paswd = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Meta:
    db_table = "employee"
```

I am getting an error message like

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1075, 'Incorrect table definition;
>   there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the **max_length** parameter for eid primary key. As below:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    eid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=<any relevant integer value>)
    ename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    paswd = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "employee"
```

Also, class Meta should define inside the model class. Other than that it is working fine for me. Please do the changes and try to run.

Comment: I did this tables are getting added in database but on terminal it is still showing me those errors. But tables are stored properly so I am ignoring those errors